# Elasticsearch. filtered query with partial_fields possible?

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to exclude certain field from result ? I'm using filtered query like this:

```
{
    "size": 10,
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "should": [
                        {
                            "text": {
                                "name": {
                                    "query": "list",
                                    "operator": "or",
                                    "boost": 30
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "text": {
                                "field2": {
                                    "query": "list",
                                    "operator": "or",
                                    "boost": 0.2
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "text": {
                                "field1": {
                                    "query": "list",
                                    "operator": "or",
                                    "boost": 0.02
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "and": [
                    {
                        "term": {
                            "_type": "product"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "filter": {
            "partial_fields": {
                "exclude": "field3"
            }
        }
    },
    "sort": [
        {
            "_score": "desc"
        }
    ]
}
```

I've added **filter partial_fields** but it does not seem to have any effect. I'm using **ES 0.9**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

partial_fields can return a partial representation of _source based on include and exclude patterns

So i guess you should specify a wildcard pattern for field name in exclude. If your field name is DATA then the exclude pattern should be DAT*..

Comment: Yes, my problem was that value for fields should hav been in "array" "exclude": ["field3"]

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that partial_fields support has been deprecated as of 1.0.0beta -

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-fields.html#partial

I know you're on 0.9 but at some point you'll need to upgrade and this approach won't work. I'd suggest upgrading to a 1.x release and using source filtering instead:

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-source-filtering.html